# Slow interaction with UI when not virtualized items

Tags: c#, wpf, virtualization

We have a rather large Dashboard WPF Application, which uses a ListView/Gridview solution to display about 400 items represented in cells.

Each cell has a ContentControl With a ContentTemplateSelector, which changes the template depending on a Property on the bound dataobject.

Earlier we were using this With normal ListView Virtualization, but my users are complaining that the scrolling experience is rather poor, and I agree.

When we deactivate the Virtualization by enabling som grouping or manual deactivating of the virtualization, the scrolling becomes as smooth as an equivalent Excel sheet (which are what we are building an app to replace). But Our interactions within the datatemplate becomes horrible slow. Meaning that when we for example use Context menu within the template and the user right click, it takes 2-3 Seconds before the context menu appears. Same With a click on a hyperlink within the template. It takes 2-3 second before something happends.

Have you guys any tips on how to debug this?

Attached is a Picture of the Dashboard:

[image: 20 columns, 40 rows]

Example of the most used datatemplate for the item in cell:

```
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding DtoParent, ElementName=userControl}" d:DataContext="{Binding DtoParent,Source={StaticResource ucVm}}" >
    <Grid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="test"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Grid.ContextMenu>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Objekt}">
        <ScrollViewer ScrollChanged="dataTemplatePresentasjonKampanjeDetalj_ScrollViewer_ScrollChanged" PreviewMouseWheel="dataTemplatePresentasjonKampanjeDetalj_ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel">
            <Border BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="1" Padding="2" CornerRadius="5" MouseMove="Border_MouseMove" PreviewMouseDown="Border_PreviewMouseDown" Tag="{Binding}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="Kopier hele kampanjedetaljen" x:Name="miKampanjeDetaljCopy" Click="miKampanjeDetaljCopy_Click" Tag="{Binding}" />
                            <MenuItem Header="Lim inn varegruppe" x:Name="miLimInnVareGruppe" Click="miLimInnVareGruppe_Click" Tag="{Binding}">
                                <MenuItem.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="MenuItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MenuItem}}">
                                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DtoVersjonKampanje.Låst}" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </MenuItem.Style>
                            </MenuItem>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Grid.ContextMenu>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Grid">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DtoVersjonKampanjeDetalj.ErEkaFerdig}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Style>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Viewbox Width="16" Height="16" Visibility="{Binding DtoVersjonElement.KunNett, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}" ToolTip="Gjelder kun for Nettapotek">
                            <Rectangle Width="16" Height="16">
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <DrawingBrush>
                                        <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                            <DrawingGroup>
                                                <DrawingGroup.Children>
                                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#00FFFFFF" Geometry="F1M16,16L0,16 0,0 16,0z" />
                                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFF6F6F6" Geometry="F1M16,8C16,12.418 12.418,16 8,16 3.582,16 0,12.418 0,8 0,3.582 3.582,0 8,0 12.418,0 16,3.582 16,8" />
                                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFF06421" Geometry="F1M9.3838,13.5752C9.9298,12.4292 10.3508,11.3602 10.6218,10.3822 11.5158,10.2662 12.4668,10.0392 13.5078,9.6472 12.9298,11.5842 11.3578,13.0872 9.3838,13.5752 M2.4858,9.6252C3.2838,9.8692 4.1978,10.1032 5.2308,10.2692 5.4368,11.3162 5.7728,12.3862 6.2118,13.4632 4.4218,12.8772 3.0208,11.4382 2.4858,9.6252 M2.2498,8.0002C2.2498,7.1802 2.4238,6.4032 2.7328,5.6982 3.4178,5.8992 4.1808,6.0912 5.0318,6.2362 4.9898,6.6412 4.9598,7.0572 4.9548,7.4942 4.9488,8.0292 4.9888,8.5772 5.0538,9.1312 3.9778,8.9352 3.0478,8.6672 2.2708,8.4032 2.2608,8.2692 2.2498,8.1362 2.2498,8.0002 M5.9168,2.6452C5.6268,3.3682 5.3608,4.2002 5.1848,5.1532 4.4928,5.0332 3.8608,4.8802 3.2818,4.7182 3.9298,3.7882 4.8458,3.0622 5.9168,2.6452 M7.9998,2.2502C8.1648,2.2502 8.3268,2.2612 8.4878,2.2742 8.9558,3.0862 9.4318,4.1202 9.7088,5.3822 9.1378,5.4212 8.5758,5.4262 8.0058,5.4212 7.4058,5.4142 6.8248,5.3732 6.2668,5.3102 6.4998,4.0952 6.8848,3.0962 7.2678,2.3022 7.5078,2.2712 7.7508,2.2502 7.9998,2.2502 M8.0058,9.4212C7.3698,9.4142 6.7578,9.3672 6.1678,9.2982 6.0838,8.6882 6.0388,8.0892 6.0448,7.5052 6.0488,7.1192 6.0758,6.7502 6.1128,6.3902 6.7148,6.4592 7.3428,6.5042 7.9938,6.5112 8.1288,6.5122 8.2628,6.5132 8.3978,6.5132 8.8858,6.5132 9.3798,6.4972 9.8848,6.4592 9.9228,6.7982 9.9508,7.1442 9.9548,7.5062 9.9608,8.0832 9.8868,8.7082 9.7458,9.3752 9.1618,9.4162 8.5878,9.4242 8.0058,9.4212 M7.9998,13.7502C7.8298,13.7502 7.6618,13.7392 7.4958,13.7242 6.9928,12.6082 6.6088,11.5002 6.3678,10.4192 6.8918,10.4712 7.4348,10.5052 7.9938,10.5112 8.1288,10.5122 8.2628,10.5122 8.3978,10.5122 8.7448,10.5122 9.0968,10.5032 9.4508,10.4852 9.1458,11.4762 8.6928,12.5622 8.0988,13.7452 8.0658,13.7462 8.0328,13.7502 7.9998,13.7502 M12.7488,4.7602C12.0628,4.9962 11.4148,5.1602 10.7978,5.2562 10.5838,4.2242 10.2468,3.3372 9.8808,2.5712 11.0568,2.9782 12.0598,3.7512 12.7488,4.7602 M10.9688,6.3382C11.6948,6.2242 12.4628,6.0302 13.2848,5.7352 13.5838,6.4302 13.7498,7.1952 13.7498,8.0002 13.7498,8.1262 13.7388,8.2492 13.7318,8.3742 12.6938,8.8262 11.7598,9.0962 10.8838,9.2372 10.9938,8.6252 11.0508,8.0432 11.0448,7.4942 11.0408,7.0942 11.0098,6.7122 10.9688,6.3382 M14.9998,8.0002C14.9998,7.9202 14.9898,7.8432 14.9878,7.7632 14.8628,4.0082 11.7858,1.0002 7.9998,1.0002 4.1338,1.0002 0.9998,4.1342 0.9998,8.0002 0.9998,8.2042 1.0118,8.4052 1.0298,8.6042 1.0458,8.7832 1.0708,8.9602 1.1008,9.1362 1.1018,9.1412 1.1018,9.1472 1.1028,9.1532 1.5918,12.0962 3.9088,14.4112 6.8528,14.8982 6.8598,14.8992 6.8658,14.9002 6.8728,14.9012 7.0468,14.9302 7.2218,14.9542 7.3998,14.9702 7.5978,14.9882 7.7968,15.0002 7.9998,15.0002 8.2318,15.0002 8.4598,14.9872 8.6848,14.9662 12.2298,14.6212 14.9998,11.6352 14.9998,8.0002" />
                                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFEFEFF0" Geometry="F1M10.9687,6.3384C11.6957,6.2244 12.4627,6.0304 13.2847,5.7344 13.5837,6.4304 13.7497,7.1954 13.7497,8.0004 13.7497,8.1264 13.7397,8.2494 13.7317,8.3744 12.6937,8.8264 11.7597,9.0954 10.8837,9.2374 10.9937,8.6254 11.0507,8.0434 11.0447,7.4944 11.0407,7.0944 11.0097,6.7124 10.9687,6.3384" />
                                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFEFEFF0" Geometry="F1M12.749,4.7598C12.063,4.9958 11.415,5.1598 10.798,5.2558 10.584,4.2248 10.247,3.3368 9.881,2.5718 11.057,2.9788 12.06,3.7508 12.749,4.7598" />
                                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFEFEFF0" Geometry="F1M8,13.75C7.83,13.75 7.662,13.739 7.496,13.725 6.993,12.608 6.608,11.5 6.368,10.419 6.892,10.471 7.435,10.505 7.994,10.511 8.129,10.513 8.263,10.513 8.398,10.513 8.745,10.513 9.097,10.503 9.451,10.485 9.146,11.477 8.692,12.563 8.099,13.745 8.065,13.746 8.033,13.75 8,13.75" />
                                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFEFEFF0" Geometry="F1M8,9.4209C7.364,9.4139 6.69,9.3189 6.1,9.2499 6.016,8.6409 6.039,8.0889 6.045,7.5049 6.049,7.1189 6.076,6.7509 6.112,6.3909 6.715,6.4589 7.349,6.5039 8,6.5109 8.135,6.5119 8.265,6.5129 8.4,6.5129 8.888,6.5129 9.38,6.4979 9.885,6.4599 9.923,6.7979 9.951,7.1439 9.955,7.5059 9.961,8.0829 9.841,8.7079 9.7,9.3749 9.116,9.4159 8.582,9.4239 8,9.4209" />
                                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFEFEFF0" Geometry="F1M8,2.25C8.165,2.25 8.327,2.261 8.488,2.274 8.956,3.086 9.423,4.12 9.7,5.382 9.129,5.421 8.57,5.426 8,5.421 7.4,5.415 6.759,5.374 6.2,5.31 6.434,4.095 6.885,3.096 7.268,2.302 7.508,2.271 7.751,2.25 8,2.25" />
                                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFEFEFF0" Geometry="F1M5.917,2.645C5.627,3.368 5.361,4.2 5.185,5.153 4.493,5.033 3.86,4.88 3.282,4.718 3.93,3.788 4.846,3.062 5.917,2.645" />
                                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFEFEFF0" Geometry="F1M2.25,8C2.25,7.181 2.424,6.403 2.732,5.698 3.418,5.899 4.181,6.091 5.032,6.236 4.99,6.642 4.96,7.057 4.955,7.494 4.949,8.029 4.989,8.577 5.054,9.131 3.977,8.935 3.048,8.667 2.27,8.403 2.261,8.27 2.25,8.136 2.25,8" />
                                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFEFEFF0" Geometry="F1M2.4863,9.625C3.2843,9.869 4.1983,10.104 5.2303,10.27 5.4363,11.316 5.7723,12.386 6.2123,13.463 4.4223,12.877 3.0203,11.439 2.4863,9.625" />
                                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFEFEFF0" Geometry="F1M9.3838,13.5752C9.9298,12.4292 10.3508,11.3602 10.6218,10.3822 11.5158,10.2662 12.4668,10.0392 13.5078,9.6472 12.9298,11.5842 11.3578,13.0872 9.3838,13.5752" />
                                                </DrawingGroup.Children>
                                            </DrawingGroup>
                                        </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                    </DrawingBrush>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>
                        </Viewbox>

                        <Viewbox Width="16" Height="16" Visibility="{Binding DtoVersjonElement.AvvikendePeriode, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}" ToolTip="Avvikende periode OK">
                            <Rectangle Width="16" Height="16">
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <DrawingBrush>
                                        <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                            <DrawingGroup>
                                                <DrawingGroup.Children>
                                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#00FFFFFF" Geometry="F1M16,16L0,16 0,0 16,0z" />
                                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFF6F6F6" Geometry="F1M15,2L15,15 1,15 1,2 4,2 4,1 7,1 7,2 9,2 9,1 12,1 12,2z" />
                                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF424242" Geometry="F1M10.5957,11.9639L10.5957,11.2149 9.1267,11.2149 9.1267,11.2019 9.4867,10.9019C10.0507,10.3989 10.5247,9.8769 10.5247,9.2229 10.5247,8.5159 10.0387,7.9999 9.1577,7.9999 8.6297,7.9999 8.1737,8.1799 7.8797,8.4019L8.1377,9.0559C8.3417,8.8999 8.6357,8.7319 8.9707,8.7319 9.4207,8.7319 9.6137,8.9839 9.6137,9.3009 9.6017,9.7569 9.1877,10.1949 8.3357,10.9569L7.8317,11.4119 7.8317,11.9639z M5.9057,11.9639L6.7867,11.9639 6.7867,8.0659 6.0317,8.0659 4.9997,8.5459 5.1497,9.2299 5.8937,8.8759 5.9057,8.8759z M12.9997,6.9999L2.9997,6.9999 2.9997,12.9999 12.9997,12.9999z M13.9997,2.9999L13.9997,13.9999 1.9997,13.9999 1.9997,2.9999 3.9997,2.9999 3.9997,4.9999 6.9997,4.9999 6.9997,2.9999 8.9997,2.9999 8.9997,4.9999 11.9997,4.9999 11.9997,2.9999z M10.9997,1.9999L9.9997,1.9999 9.9997,3.9999 10.9997,3.9999z M5.9997,3.9999L4.9997,3.9999 4.9997,1.9999 5.9997,1.9999z" />
                                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFF0EFF1" Geometry="F1M10.5957,11.9639L7.8317,11.9639 7.8317,11.4119 8.3357,10.9569C9.1877,10.1949 9.6017,9.7569 9.6137,9.3009 9.6137,8.9839 9.4207,8.7319 8.9707,8.7319 8.6357,8.7319 8.3417,8.8999 8.1377,9.0559L7.8797,8.4019C8.1737,8.1799 8.6297,7.9999 9.1577,7.9999 10.0387,7.9999 10.5247,8.5159 10.5247,9.2229 10.5247,9.8769 10.0507,10.3989 9.4867,10.9019L9.1267,11.2019 9.1267,11.2149 10.5957,11.2149z M6.7867,11.9639L5.9057,11.9639 5.9057,8.8759 5.8937,8.8759 5.1497,9.2299 4.9997,8.5459 6.0317,8.0659 6.7867,8.0659z M2.9997,12.9999L12.9997,12.9999 12.9997,6.9999 2.9997,6.9999z M2.9997,6.9999" />
                                                </DrawingGroup.Children>
                                            </DrawingGroup>
                                        </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                    </DrawingBrush>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>
                        </Viewbox>
                        <Viewbox Width="16" Height="16" Visibility="{Binding AvvikendePeriodeValidertFeil, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}" ToolTip="Avvikende periode mangler, eller er feil utfyllt">
                            <Rectangle Width="16" Height="16">
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <DrawingBrush>
                                        <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                            <DrawingGroup>
                                                <DrawingGroup.Children>
                                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#00FFFFFF" Geometry="F1M16,16L0,16 0,0 16,0z" />
                                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFF6F6F6" Geometry="F1M0.9999,0.999700000000001L0.9999,6.9997 2.9999,6.9997 2.9999,14.9997 15.9999,14.9997 15.9999,0.999700000000001z" />
                                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF1AA1E2" Geometry="F1M3,3L9,3 9,5 3,5z M14,3L12,5 10,3z M2,6L4,6 5,6 14,6 15,6 15,2 2,2z" />
                                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFC17C1A" Geometry="F1M13,12L10,12 10,9 13,9z" />
                                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFEFEFF0" Geometry="F1M13,7L12,7 12,8 13,8z M13,9L10,9 10,12 13,12z M9,7L8,7 8,8 9,8z M9,9L8,9 8,10 9,10z M9,11L8,11 8,12 9,12z M7,9L6,9 6,10 7,10z M7,11L6,11 6,12 7,12z M10,8L11,8 11,7 10,7z M14,13L5,13 5,6 14,6z M14,3L10,3 12,5z M3,3L9,3 9,5 3,5z" />
                                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF424242" Geometry="F1M7,9L6,9 6,10 7,10z M7,11L6,11 6,12 7,12z M14,13L5,13 5,6 4,6 4,14 15,14 15,6 14,6z M11,7L10,7 10,8 11,8z M13,7L12,7 12,8 13,8z M9,11L8,11 8,12 9,12z M9,9L8,9 8,10 9,10z M9,8L8,8 8,7 9,7z" />
                                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFEFEFF0" Geometry="F1M14,3L10,3 12,5z" />
                                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFEFEFF0" Geometry="F1M9,3L3,3 3,5 9,5z" />
                                                </DrawingGroup.Children>
                                            </DrawingGroup>
                                        </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                    </DrawingBrush>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>
                        </Viewbox>
                        <Viewbox Width="16" Height="16" Visibility="{Binding DtoVersjonKampanjeDetalj.ErDirekteutsendelse, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}" ToolTip="Varer skal direkteutsendes">
                            <Rectangle Width="16" Height="16">
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <DrawingBrush>
                                        <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                            <DrawingGroup>
                                                <DrawingGroup.Children>
                                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#00FFFFFF" Geometry="F1M16,16L0,16 0,0 16,0z" />
                                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFF6F6F6" Geometry="F1M10.4346,14L4.4936,14C4.0296,14.617 3.2956,15 2.4996,15 1.1216,15 -0.000400000000000844,13.879 -0.000400000000000844,12.5 -0.000400000000000844,11.121 1.1216,10 2.4996,10 3.2956,10 4.0296,10.383 4.4936,11L10.4346,11 11.4346,10 10.4346,9 4.4936,9C4.0296,9.617 3.2956,10 2.4996,10 1.1216,10 -0.000400000000000844,8.878 -0.000400000000000844,7.5 -0.000400000000000844,6.122 1.1216,5 2.4996,5 3.2956,5 4.0296,5.383 4.4936,6L10.4346,6 11.4346,5 10.4346,4 4.4936,4C4.0296,4.617 3.2956,5 2.4996,5 1.1216,5 -0.000400000000000844,3.878 -0.000400000000000844,2.5 -0.000400000000000844,1.122 1.1216,0 2.4996,0 3.2956,0 4.0296,0.382999999999999 4.4936,1L10.4346,1 11.4346,0 13.5046,0 15.9996,2.495 15.9996,2.505 13.5046,5 15.9996,7.495 15.9996,7.505 13.5046,10 15.9996,12.495 15.9996,12.505 12.5046,16 12.4346,16z" />
                                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF424242" Geometry="F1M11.7627,11.0859L12.6767,11.9999 3.9087,11.9999C3.7017,11.4189 3.1517,10.9999 2.4997,10.9999 1.6717,10.9999 0.999700000000001,11.6719 0.999700000000001,12.4999 0.999700000000001,13.3279 1.6717,13.9999 2.4997,13.9999 3.1517,13.9999 3.7017,13.5809 3.9087,12.9999L12.6767,12.9999 11.7627,13.9139 12.4697,14.6209 14.5907,12.4999 12.4697,10.3789z M11.7627,6.0859L12.6767,6.9999 3.9087,6.9999C3.7017,6.4189 3.1517,5.9999 2.4997,5.9999 1.6717,5.9999 0.999700000000001,6.6719 0.999700000000001,7.4999 0.999700000000001,8.3279 1.6717,8.9999 2.4997,8.9999 3.1517,8.9999 3.7017,8.5809 3.9087,7.9999L12.6767,7.9999 11.7627,8.9139 12.4697,9.6209 14.5907,7.4999 12.4697,5.3789z M0.999700000000001,2.4999C0.999700000000001,1.6719 1.6717,0.999899999999998 2.4997,0.999899999999998 3.1517,0.999899999999998 3.7017,1.4189 3.9087,1.9999L12.6767,1.9999 11.7627,1.0859 12.4697,0.378899999999998 14.5907,2.4999 12.4697,4.6209 11.7627,3.9139 12.6767,2.9999 3.9087,2.9999C3.7017,3.5809 3.1517,3.9999 2.4997,3.9999 1.6717,3.9999 0.999700000000001,3.3279 0.999700000000001,2.4999" />
                                                </DrawingGroup.Children>
                                            </DrawingGroup>
                                        </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                    </DrawingBrush>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>
                        </Viewbox>
                        <Viewbox Width="16" Height="16"  Visibility="{Binding HarKundeklubbTilbud, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}" ToolTip="Inneholder kundeklubb tilbud">
                            <Rectangle Width="16" Height="16">
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <DrawingBrush>
                                        <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                            <DrawingGroup>
                                                <DrawingGroup.Children>
                                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#00FFFFFF" Geometry="F1M16,16L0,16 0,0 16,0z" />
                                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFF6F6F6" Geometry="F1M16,15L8.656,15C7.763,15.629 6.676,16 5.5,16 4.324,16 3.237,15.629 2.344,15L0,15 0,1 16,1z" />
                                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF424242" Geometry="F1M15,2L15,14 9.743,14C9.996,13.693,10.212,13.357,10.395,13L14,13 14,5 2,5 2,6.258C1.619,6.573,1.284,6.94,1,7.344L1,2z" />
                                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFF0EFF1" Geometry="F1M4.1875,7.1006C3.4995,7.3686 2.9105,7.8346 2.4945,8.4326 2.8665,8.5376 3.2725,8.6346 3.7165,8.7126 3.8315,8.1006 4.0015,7.5656 4.1875,7.1006 M6.6255,8.8596C6.4465,8.0486 6.1415,7.3846 5.8395,6.8626 5.7365,6.8546 5.6335,6.8466 5.5265,6.8466 5.3675,6.8466 5.2095,6.8606 5.0565,6.8796 4.8105,7.3906 4.5625,8.0326 4.4125,8.8146 4.7715,8.8556 5.1455,8.8806 5.5305,8.8846 5.8965,8.8886 6.2585,8.8846 6.6255,8.8596 M8.5795,8.4596C8.1365,7.8116 7.4925,7.3146 6.7355,7.0536 6.9715,7.5456 7.1875,8.1166 7.3245,8.7786 7.7235,8.7166 8.1385,8.6116 8.5795,8.4596 M9.0395,11.5926C8.3745,11.8426 7.7685,11.9886 7.1985,12.0606 7.0245,12.6856 6.7575,13.3666 6.4095,14.0976 7.6675,13.7866 8.6695,12.8276 9.0395,11.5926 M4.3875,14.0256C4.1065,13.3376 3.8925,12.6576 3.7615,11.9906 3.1035,11.8846 2.5205,11.7346 2.0115,11.5786 2.3535,12.7356 3.2455,13.6526 4.3875,14.0256 M1.8745,10.8006C2.3705,10.9676 2.9625,11.1386 3.6475,11.2636 3.6065,10.9106 3.5815,10.5606 3.5855,10.2206 3.5885,9.9416 3.6075,9.6776 3.6345,9.4176 3.0925,9.3266 2.6045,9.2046 2.1685,9.0756 1.9725,9.5256 1.8605,10.0216 1.8605,10.5426 1.8605,10.6296 1.8675,10.7146 1.8745,10.8006 M6.6405,11.4136C6.7295,10.9876 6.7765,10.5826 6.7725,10.2146 6.7705,9.9856 6.7795,9.7456 6.7545,9.5296 6.4335,9.5526 4.6975,9.5306 4.3135,9.4876 4.2905,9.7156 4.2825,10.2106 4.2805,10.4556 4.2765,10.8286 4.3055,11.0966 4.3585,11.4856 4.7345,11.5286 5.1245,11.5016 5.5305,11.5066 5.9015,11.5086 6.2675,11.4386 6.6405,11.4136 M5.5895,14.2056C5.9685,13.4516 6.2575,12.7596 6.4515,12.1266 6.2265,12.1386 6.0015,12.1446 5.7795,12.1446 5.6945,12.1446 5.6085,12.1446 5.5225,12.1426 5.1665,12.1406 4.8195,12.1186 4.4865,12.0846 4.6395,12.7736 4.8855,13.4806 5.2055,14.1916 5.3125,14.2016 5.4185,14.2086 5.5265,14.2086 5.5485,14.2086 5.5675,14.2066 5.5895,14.2056 M7.4685,10.2206C7.4725,10.5706 7.4355,10.9416 7.3645,11.3316 7.9235,11.2426 8.5195,11.0696 9.1815,10.7816 9.1855,10.7026 9.1935,10.6226 9.1935,10.5426 9.1935,10.0296 9.0855,9.5416 8.8955,9.0996 8.3725,9.2876 7.8825,9.4116 7.4195,9.4846 7.4445,9.7226 7.4655,9.9646 7.4685,10.2206 M5.4995,4.9996C8.5375,4.9996 10.9995,7.4626 10.9995,10.4996 10.9995,11.4006 10.7795,12.2496 10.3945,12.9996L14.0005,12.9996 14.0005,4.9996z M1.9995,4.9996L5.4995,4.9996C4.1695,4.9996,2.9515,5.4726,1.9995,6.2586z" />
                                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF00539C" Geometry="F1M9.2109,10.7832C8.5439,11.0742 7.9429,11.2482 7.3799,11.3382 7.4509,10.9452 7.4889,10.5702 7.4849,10.2192 7.4819,9.9602 7.4609,9.7162 7.4349,9.4752 7.9019,9.4022 8.3959,9.2772 8.9239,9.0882 9.1149,9.5332 9.2229,10.0252 9.2229,10.5432 9.2229,10.6232 9.2149,10.7032 9.2109,10.7832 M6.4179,14.1272C6.7669,13.3892 7.0379,12.7032 7.2119,12.0732 7.7869,12.0002 8.3979,11.8532 9.0679,11.6012 8.6959,12.8462 7.6849,13.8132 6.4179,14.1272 M5.5889,14.2352C5.5679,14.2362 5.5479,14.2392 5.5269,14.2392 5.4179,14.2392 5.3099,14.2312 5.2029,14.2212 4.8799,13.5052 4.6319,12.7922 4.4779,12.0972 4.8139,12.1312 5.1639,12.1542 5.5229,12.1562 5.6089,12.1582 5.6969,12.1582 5.7819,12.1582 6.0049,12.1582 6.2319,12.1522 6.4599,12.1402 6.2629,12.7782 5.9719,13.4752 5.5889,14.2352 M1.9819,11.5872C2.4949,11.7442 3.0829,11.8962 3.7469,12.0022 3.8779,12.6752 4.0949,13.3612 4.3779,14.0542 3.2269,13.6782 2.3269,12.7542 1.9819,11.5872 M1.8309,10.5432C1.8309,10.0172 1.9419,9.5172 2.1409,9.0622 2.5809,9.1932 3.0719,9.3162 3.6189,9.4082 3.5919,9.6702 3.5719,9.9362 3.5689,10.2192 3.5649,10.5602 3.5909,10.9132 3.6319,11.2692 2.9409,11.1432 2.3439,10.9702 1.8439,10.8032 1.8369,10.7172 1.8309,10.6312 1.8309,10.5432 M4.3139,9.4872C4.7009,9.5312,5.1039,9.5432,5.5229,9.5432L5.7819,9.5432C6.0959,9.5432 6.4139,9.5542 6.7379,9.5312 6.7629,9.7502 6.7819,9.9822 6.7839,10.2142 6.7879,10.5862 6.7399,10.9922 6.6489,11.4222 6.2729,11.4472 5.9049,11.4592 5.5309,11.4572 5.1209,11.4512 4.7289,11.4222 4.3489,11.3782 4.2949,10.9862 4.2669,10.5992 4.2709,10.2242 4.2729,9.9772 4.2899,9.7182 4.3139,9.4872 M4.1879,7.1002C4.0019,7.5652 3.8309,8.1002 3.7169,8.7132 3.2729,8.6352 2.8659,8.5382 2.4939,8.4322 2.9109,7.8352 3.4999,7.3682 4.1879,7.1002 M6.6259,8.8592C6.2579,8.8852 5.8969,8.8882 5.5309,8.8852 5.1449,8.8812 4.7719,8.8552 4.4119,8.8142 4.5619,8.0322 4.8099,7.3902 5.0559,6.8802 5.2099,6.8602 5.3669,6.8462 5.5269,6.8462 5.6329,6.8462 5.7369,6.8542 5.8389,6.8622 6.1409,7.3842 6.4469,8.0492 6.6259,8.8592 M8.5799,8.4592C8.1379,8.6112 7.7229,8.7172 7.3249,8.7782 7.1869,8.1162 6.9709,7.5452 6.7359,7.0532 7.4929,7.3152 8.1359,7.8112 8.5799,8.4592 M10.0199,10.3902C9.9379,7.9772 7.9609,6.0432 5.5269,6.0432 3.0419,6.0432 1.0269,8.0572 1.0269,10.5432 1.0269,10.6752 1.0349,10.8032 1.0459,10.9312 1.0559,11.0472 1.0729,11.1602 1.0919,11.2722 1.0919,11.2772 1.0919,11.2802 1.0939,11.2852 1.4069,13.1762 2.8969,14.6652 4.7899,14.9762 4.7939,14.9772 4.7979,14.9782 4.8019,14.9782 4.9149,14.9982 5.0269,15.0132 5.1409,15.0232 5.2679,15.0352 5.3969,15.0432 5.5269,15.0432 5.6749,15.0432 5.8219,15.0342 5.9659,15.0212 8.2449,14.7992 10.0269,12.8802 10.0269,10.5432 10.0269,10.4902 10.0199,10.4412 10.0199,10.3902" />
                                                </DrawingGroup.Children>
                                            </DrawingGroup>
                                        </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                    </DrawingBrush>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>
                        </Viewbox>




                        <customControls:ccAntallProdukterVisning ToolTip="Antall produkter" />
                        <!--<Button Content="{Binding DtoVersjonKampanjeDetalj.Tittel}"/>-->

                    </StackPanel>

                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ObsCollVareTittelVisning}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1"  Grid.Column="0" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="4" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource dataTemplateVareTittelVisningeHyperLink}">
                    </ItemsControl>
                    <Image Source="/WpfVFAKampanjeMaster;component/Assets/lock.png" Height="20" ToolTip="Denne kampanjen er låst for redigering"
                           VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                        <Image.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Image">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DtoVersjonKampanje.Låst}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Image.Style>
                    </Image>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>


<DataTemplate x:Key="dataTemplateVareTittelVisningeHyperLink" DataType="presentasjon:DtoKampanjeDetaljVareTittelVisning">
    <TextBlock Margin="4,0">
        <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Kopier varegruppe" x:Name="miKopierVareGruppe" Tag="{Binding}" Click="miKopierVareGruppe_Click" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
        <Hyperlink Tag="{Binding}" x:Name="hyperLinkVareTittelVisning" Click="hyperLinkVareTittelVisning_Click">
            <Hyperlink.ToolTip>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ObsCollTilbud}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Navn}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Hyperlink.ToolTip>
            <TextBlock MaxWidth="300" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DtoVersjonKampanjeDetaljVareTittel.Tittel}" Foreground="{Binding DtoVersjonKampanjeDetaljVareTittel.Status,Converter={StaticResource EnumVaretittelForgrunnsFargeConverter}}" />
                <customControls:ccVareTittelTilbudVisning ObsCollTilbud="{Binding ObsCollTilbud}" Margin="-0,0,0,-3" />
            </TextBlock>
        </Hyperlink>
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: What virtualization modes have you tried so far?

Comment: Recycling and Standard for default listview without grouping. And then of course grouping.


When not virtualizing the initial load of the items into view takes about 15 Seconds, but that we can live with, since we have built a waiting window on a separate thread with some animations for the user to look at. But we cannot live With 2-3 second delay on right click context menu, or left click on link. 


The memory usage for the UI part is around 500MB, which also is high, but we can live with that

Comment: I will look into this hierarchy today I was a bit busy yesterday. But what I can see is that the entire grid has the context menu attached to it, so even if the user clicks on the border part of the grid it will still show the context menu and execute the actions specified. This can cause errors or unexpected behaviour, also could you add the `dataTemplateVareTittelVisningeHyperLink` DataTemplate as well?

Comment: Thank you.

The context menu on the grid was a test, which are removed, and still same performance issues. 

Also, even mouse click event on the hyperlink takes 5+ Seconds for the click event to be fired.

Will update the original post With dataTemplateVareTittelVisningeHyperLink

Comment: Can you do a bitbucket project? With the code so I can reproduce the issue? Cause I can't see the code that creates those 20 columns. There is a performance hit when it comes to the horizontal scrolling but I think we can simplify the template a bit to increase the performance.

Comment: Hmm, that is somewhat dificult because you need both SQL database and WCF service to get the data.


I have so far identified that hyperlink takes a good chunk out of the performance, so am currently rebuilding the Visual without standard hyperlink.

Also i tried to set IsHitTestVisible to false in the parent template. This made huge difference in activiation/deactiviation of the window. 


So it seems to me that the native HitTest function makes a great performance hit. Now I am trying to figure out how to properly handle this hittest issue, without losing any features

Comment: Also the data creation takes a couple of Seconds. We are using reflection to create a custom Class for each row, With different Object types based on what is needed in the UI.

Each row is stored in a ObservableCollection<Object> which are bound trough a CollectionviewSource and then bound to Listview/GridView.

This also takes time, but is done while the Wait screen animations are dancing in front of the user, so we belivie this is Ok

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so many changes needed to get the performance.

Now we have come closer to acceptable performance.

1.Remove all TextBlock with hyperlinks.

2.Change from UserControl to CustomControl

3.And the one that really made a great difference:

```
public class CustomListView : ListView
{
    protected override void OnIsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //huge performance hit if next line is not commented out
        //base.OnIsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged(e);
    }
}
```

We actually ended up With about 45 second inital load time. But since we have a progress window for intial load, this should be acceptable.

But now the app is snappy and responsive after inital load.

As we use Callback contracts from WCF server to push all incremental data changes to all Connected Clients, it has become a really good Dashboard app.

Comment: Instead of `CustomControl` I would use a `DataTemplate`. With appropriate style and triggers you can improve the performance even more. Glad you got there in the end :-).
FYI I only need the data structures to populate the grid :-)